# passing pointer to SDL function

Tags: pointers, sdl

I'm trying to understand why method1 works, and method2 doesnt work, when I'm passing "offset" to SDL_BlitSurface function.

USAGE:

```
int SDL_BlitSurface(SDL_Surface *src,  SDL_Rect *srcrect,  SDL_Surface *dst, SDL_Rect *dstrect);
```

In my mind, both should work, since SDL_BlitSurface function asks SDL_Rect* as the 4th input argument. And in both cases I have passed a SDL_Rect* to the function. However method2 yields "Unhandled exception Access violation writing location error". Please help!

method1:

```
SDL_Rect offset;
offset.x = 1;
SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, &offset );
```

method2:

```
SDL_Rect* offset = NULL;
offset->x = 1;
SDL_BlitSurface( source, NULL, destination, offset );
```

(Code from Lazy Foo's tutorial Lesson 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer variable (like `offset`) holds an address, just like a house address.
The structure tells the computer who lives in the house in each room (the rooms have names, for example `x`).

The problem is that you first say: "`offset` is a fake address (call it NULL)." and then you say "and in room `x` lives 1". So this doesn't make sense - the number 1 can live in room `x` only if the address is real. Nobody can live in a fake address.

Unfortunately, you can write whatever you want in the code. Only when you run it and try to put 1 in room `x` the computer shouts. "Access violation" basically means: "you're trying to put some data in an address that you don't have access to". In this case, the fake address NULL is not an address you can store anything in.

If you follow Armin's suggestion, then `offset` will point to a valid address, and that will allow you to store 1 in the room `x`. Method 1 solves the problem by passing the address of a pre-allocated structure `offset` (it's allocated automatically by the compiler on the stack).

Answer (score 1):

In the *second case* you haven't reserved any memory for `offset` since `SDL_Rect* offset` is just a pointer, you have to allocate memory for it to point to something:

Example in `c`:

```
SDL_Rect* offset = malloc( sizeof( SDL_Rect ) );
```

Then you second method will work.